# PhantomJS screenshot image works, but it is very slow

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phantomjs, render

I need to capture a web animation from different pages, need at least 50 FPS to capture the smooth animation, phantomJS cannot capture at 50 FPS, so, I play the animation x times slower and loop using setInterval every X ms and capture the image using phantomJS render.

Also, I need to scale this in a large scale, tried executing pages in parallel, but no luck.

In a 32 Core processor, 64GB RAM Ubuntu machine could handle only 25 such pages parallelly and takes about 20 minutes to complete, this is really very very slow to scale.

Any suggestions to improve?

Code sample,

```
page.open(system.args[1],function(status){
    if(status=="success"){ // on successful page open
        setTimeout(function(){ // wait 1 second, all js css to load
            // get the number of frames
            frames = 1000;
            frame=0;
            // loop every loop_interval milli seconds
            var interval = setInterval(function() { // record each frame
                // Render an image with the frame name
                page.render('frame_' + frame + '.png', { format: "png",quality: '100' });
                frame++;
                // exit when all the frames recorded - video end
                if(frames <=frame) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    phantom.exit();
                } // if
            }, loop_interval); // set interval
        },1000); // set time out
    }else{
        console.log("Failed load page: "+system.args[1]+"\n");
        phantom.exit();
    } // ifelse status
}); // page.open
```